# Converting 1M to 1000000 elegantly

Tags: r, data.table

I want to convert:

```
library(data.table)
market.cap <- data.table(cap=c("1B", "10M", "2M"))

  cap
1  1B
2 10M
3  2M
```

to:

```
      cap
1 1000000000
2   10000000
3    2000000
```

Here's my solution. It works, but involves adding a column, which I know isn't necessary. What's a better way?

```
market.cap[, cap1 := cap]
market.cap$cap = sapply(market.cap$cap, function(x) (as.numeric(temp <- gsub("B", "", x)) * 1000000000))
market.cap$cap1 = sapply(market.cap$cap1, function(x) (as.numeric(temp <- gsub("M", "", x)) * 1000000))
M = data.frame(x = na.omit(market.cap$cap))
B = data.frame(x = na.omit(market.cap$cap1))
rbind(M,B)
```

Comment: Are there others beside B and M? If not, then maybe `with(market.cap, as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", cap)) * ifelse(grepl("B", cap), 1e9, 1e6))`

Comment: @Richard Scriven, No, only B and M. This works great. Maybe post as an answer? Some amateur questions: It seems like  `\\D`, works  as well as `\\D+`? I'm not familiar with either, what's the difference? If the second argument of `with` removes the `B`s and `M`s, how does the third argument, which searches for `B`, possibly find it? Hasn't it just been removed?

Comment: protip: `market.cap <- data.table(cap = c("1B", "10M", "2M"))` is sufficient

Comment: In fact, using `colnames` for me caused issues immediately with Invalid `.internal.selfref` errors. Because of this I've edited your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my own attempt:

```
market.cap[ , cap1 := {
  sf <- gsub("[0-9]", "", cap)
  as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", cap)) * 1000 ^ (2 + (sf == "B"))}]
```

The following approach may prove faster since it doesn't need to waste effort on running `cap` through a regex twice:

```
market.cap[ , cap1 := {
  x<- do.call("rbind", strsplit(cap, split = "(?=[BM])", perl = TRUE))
  as.numeric(x[ , 1L]) * 1000 ^ (2 + (x[ , 2L] == "B"))}]
```

And the following may prove fastest since `tstrsplit` has been optimized in `data.table`:

```
market.cap[ , cap1 := {
  x <- tstrsplit(cap, split = "(?=[BM])", perl = TRUE)
  as.numeric(x[[1L]]) * 1000 ^ (2 + (x[[2]] == "B"))}]
```

Comment: You are correct good sir! Mean times with microbenchmark:
solution one: 28.16288, solution two: 17.26301, solution three: 12.63196. Thanks for your help here, and the tip above.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `gsubfn`, match the non-numeric element (`\\D`), replace that with the corresponding `value` of the `list` that matches the `key`, and use `eval(parse` to convert that to numeric value.

```
library(gsubfn) 
options(scipen=999)
unname(sapply(gsubfn('\\D', list(B= '*1e9', M= '*1e6'), 
       market.cap$cap), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1] 1000000000   10000000    2000000
```

---

We can also use `match` after extracting the `numeric` and non-numeric parts, then use `match` with a vector of letters (`c('B', 'M')`) to get the numeric index and replace it with new values.

```
 market.cap[,  cap1 := as.numeric(sub('\\D', '', 
    cap))*c(1e9, 1e6)[match( sub('\\d+', '', cap), c('B', 'M'))]]
 #    cap       cap1
 #1:  1B 1000000000
 #2: 10M   10000000
 #3:  2M    2000000
```

Answer (score 4):

This is also one option:

```
# Your toy data
library("data.table")
market.cap <- data.table(c("1B", "10M", "2M"))
colnames(market.cap) <- "cap"

# Helpful functions
ssub <- function(x) gsub("B", "*1e9", gsub("M", "*1e6", x))
evalp <- function(x) eval(parse(text = x))

# Substitute and evaluate
sapply(ssub(market.cap$cap), evalp)
#1*1e9 10*1e6  2*1e6 
#1e+09  1e+07  2e+06
```